# IOException while opening the page

Tags: jsp, aem

I am getting the error while opening any page in AEM. Below is the error log. Anyone has any idea how to fix it.

```
28.09.2015 12:15:37.490 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1443422737179] GET /editor.html/content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/newsletter.html HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught SlingException
java.io.IOException: tmpFile.renameTo(classFile) failed
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil$SDEInstaller.install(SmapUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.SmapUtil.installSmap(SmapUtil.java:167)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:151)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:290)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:501)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.prepareServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:427)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:486)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
    at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:284)
```

Comment: Which version of AEM are you using? Also, I dont get the same error when I open the same page. I would suggest to browse the page using CRXDE-lite and try deleting the component nodes in that page. There might be a case where you have a component included on the page and that component no longer exists.

Comment: It was the issue of JRE. I didn't had JRE on system.